# How to tell if server is sending mail

Tags: ubuntu, email-server

I would like to be able to check if my server is sending out emails even whilst PHP's validation is returning true.

I am unsure if my server is currently sending out emails.

How can one test to make sure that an email has indeed been sent out from the server?

Are there any ways to check if the email has been sent, I don't need to check if it has been received but just sent.

Comment: Are you asking about *sending* mail or *receiving* mail?  The title and the body of your question seem to disagree with each other.  In both cases, the answer would be to look in your mail logs.  Have you done that yet?  If you have, please add it to your question.

Comment: Ubuntu ***6***? Really?  Time to upgrade.  OSes aren't Twinkies.  They're not meant to survive a nuclear apocalypse, or a decade on the shelf.

Comment: @HopelessN00b heh, indeed but i'm sticking with if it an't broken don't fix it

Comment: @Ladadadada updated the question as you're right, it was poorly written. I haven't checked the logs. Not sure where i would find the mail logs?

Comment: In recent versions of Ubuntu, the logs for both sending and receiving are in `/var/log/mail.log`.  This is probably true for ancient versions as well.  Certainly in `/var/log/`.

Comment: You need to look at your log files and to a little troubleshooting -- this question is unanswerable in its current state.  See also [this meta question on how to ask good questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) for some idea of the minimum level of information we need to start helping you...

Comment: was ubuntu 8.04 in the end :) Anyway, can we delete this question please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
telnet yuor.server.ip 25
```

You should get something like

```
220 your.mail.server ESMTP
```

Comment: indeed, 220 sub.domain.com ESMTP, i assume this means my mail server is running as expected?

Comment: You should check the logs to be sure. Even if it works as expected it could be blacklisted.

Comment: This is about whether you server can receive mail or not.  As per your updated question, it's not really relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Check blacklists, check logs. The logs in /var/log/mail.log should tell you whats going on.